How to broadcast to different app using laravel reverb?
I have problem with multiple app setup for laravel reverb. Only 1 app is listening to the broadcast, but the other is not.
So i have this setup of laravel reverb.
broadcasting.php
'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver'  => 'pusher',
            'key'     => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret'  => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id'  => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                // 'cluster'   => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => env('PUSHER_ENCRYPTED'),
                'host'      => env('PUSHER_HOST', 'pusher.runcloud.io'),
                'port'      => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
                'scheme'    => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
            ],
        ],

.env
REVERB_APP_ID=app
REVERB_APP_KEY=app_key
REVERB_APP_SECRET=app_secret
REVERB_HOST=laravel-reverb.test
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=https

and my reverb.php is
'apps' => [

        'provider' => 'config',

        'apps' => [
            [
                'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
                'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
                'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
                'options' => [
                    'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                    'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                    'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
                ],
                'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
                'ping_interval' => env('REVERB_APP_PING_INTERVAL', 60),
                'activity_timeout' => env('REVERB_APP_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT', 30),
                'max_message_size' => env('REVERB_APP_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE', 10_000),
            ], [
                'key' => 'dev_' . env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
                'secret' => 'dev_' .env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
                'app_id' => 'dev_' .env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
                'options' => [
                    'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                    'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                    'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
                ],
                'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
                'ping_interval' => env('REVERB_APP_PING_INTERVAL', 60),
                'activity_timeout' => env('REVERB_APP_ACTIVITY_TIMEOUT', 30),
                'max_message_size' => env('REVERB_APP_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE', 10_000),
            ],
        ],

So i setup my clients like so
reverb_Test = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'app_key',
    wsHost: 'laravel-reverb.test',
    wsPort: '8080',
    wssPort: '8080',
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true
})

reverb_Test_Two = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'dev_app_key',,
    wsHost: 'laravel-reverb.test',
    wsPort: '8080',
    wssPort: '8080',
    encrypted: true,
    disableStats: true
})

reverb_Test.channel('delivery')
    .listen('deliver', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });

reverb_Test_Two.channel('delivery')
    .listen('deliver', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });

and i test my broadcasting like so...
Broadcast::on('delivery')
        ->toOthers()
        ->sendNow();

Broadcast::on('delivery')
        ->sendNow();

When I broadcast, I only received that events on reverb_test client and nothing on reverb_test_two client.
It's best to note that both client is successfully subscribed to delivery channel and deliver event but only reverb_test receive it.
Why is that? and how can i receive on both clients or if can pick which app i want to broadcast to.
